# MP4 file not loading on React / Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, video, mp4

I'm getting this error. From what I can google, it needs to configure the webpack file but in this rails app it's a webpacker.yml file. CRA looks like it works fine when using the usual  tag. Any help would be appreciated.

> ./app/javascript/components/User/cover.mp4 1:0 Module parse failed:
> Unexpected character '' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to
> handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process
> this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code
> omitted for this binary file)

```
  "dependencies": {
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
"@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0-alpha",
"@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0-alpha",
"@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0-alpha",
"@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
"animate.css": "^4.1.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-animate-on-scroll": "^2.1.5",
"react-animations": "^1.0.0",
"react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^5.1.15",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-ga": "^3.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scroll": "^1.8.0",
"styled-components": "^5.1.1",
"turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
```

},
"version": "0.1.0",
"devDependencies": {
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
}

Comment: The URL in the error message is pointing you in the right direction. However, it sounds like you're using some other package to manage your build - I don't know anything about `webpacker.yml` files - so in this case, you'll need to investigate whatever is using that file to build your project.

Comment: @Kryten, thanks for the push. I ended up reading how webpacker.yml works. It talks to config/webpack files in a rails configuration. the config/webpack/{dev/prod/test/env} files is === webpack.config.js.  I did `yarn add url-loader` then added to config/webpack/environment.js file

`const { environment } = require("@rails/webpacker");

const fileLoader = environment.loaders.get("file");
fileLoader.test = /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|tiff|ico|svg|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|webm|mp4)$/i;

module.exports = environment;`

answer was here [git link](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1591)

Answer (score 0):

in `config/webpacker.yml` under `static_assets_extensions` add `.mp4`

```
static_assets_extensions
  - .mp4
  ...
```

create a new folder `app/javascripts/static`

then

```
const file = require('static/file.mp4')

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <video controls>
        <source src={file} />
      </video>
  ...
```

> Note: You should use CDN to deliver videos

Comment: interesting. i tried this approach earlier today but it didn't work so i scrapped it. but tried it again just now and it worked. I guess my other comment answer is another way to do it too. Thanks!

Comment: However this is only working for dev environment and not production. its failing on compile in heroku. > Compiling...
       Compilation failed:
       ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './cover.mp4' in '/tmp/build_775cbf44_/app/javascript/components/Navbar'
           at /tmp/build_775cbf44_/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:925:10 ...  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
           using description file: /tmp/build_775cbf44_/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/components/Navbar/cover.mp4)
             no extension

Comment: Try to compile it locally

Comment: sorry for dumb question, compile how? The video is working locally.